# Conditional probability given that the data are normally distributed.

Tags: probability

> Suppose that when you tell a person to show up at noon, the actual time they show up has a normal distribution with average noon but with an SD of 15 minutes. You tell thirty people to show up at noon. Assume they all arrive independently of each other and that time is continuous.

I would like to verify if my solution is correct.

> 1).What is the chance that the earliest person came before 11:30, given that they were all there by noon?

I don't get why we can't simply apply $\frac {P(Earliest \, came \,  before \,11:30\, \cap All\, there\, by\, noon)}{P(All\, there\, by\, noon)}$

For P(Earliest came before 1130) I got $1-0.97^{30}$

$\frac {P(Earliest \, came \,  before \,11:30\, \cap All\, there\, by\, noon)}{P(All\, there\, by\, noon)}= \frac {(1-o.97^{30})*0.5^{30}}{0.5^{30}}$

The above solution doesn't look right to me

I decided to try it with Bayes' Theorem:

P(Earliest before 11:30 | All there by noon)=

$\frac {P(All \, there \, by \, noon | Earliest \, before \, 11:30) * P(Earliest \, before \, 11:30)}{P(All \, there  \, by \, noon)}= \frac {1*(1-0.9772^{30})}{0.5^{30}}$

> 2).What is the chance that they will all be there by noon, given that you know that the earliest one came before 11:30?

I used Bayes' Theorem on this problem as well:

P(All there by noon | Earliest before 11:30)=

$\frac {P(Earliest \, before \, 11:30 | \,All \, there \, by \, noon  ) * P( \,All \, there \, by \, noon  )}{P(Earliest \, before \, 11:30)}= \frac {(1-0.9772^{30})*(0.5^{30})}{1-0.9772^{30}}$

I'm quite sure I did something wrong here.

Edit: The more I read question 2) I'm not even sure what it means. What I got out of it is "What is the chance of all 30 people show up before 12:00PM, knowing that the earliest person showed up before 11:30AM" So that means at least we know 1 person showed up before noon time, so then we only need to find the probability that the remaining 29 people who show up before 12:00PM ????

Comment: You made the error of thinking $P(\text{earliestb4 11:30}\cap \text{allbynoon})=P(\text{earliestb4 11:30})\cdot P(\text{allbynoon})$.  Remember that $P(A\cap B)\neq P(A)\cdot P(B)$ in general.  You may only split apart like that if you know ahead of time that the events are independent.

Comment: $P(\text{allbynoon}\mid\text{earliestb4 11:30})$ should not be equal to $1$.  Think a bit more about that one. (*we know fastest person arrived before 11:30, and the remaining $29$ people are essentially unknown to us*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be the event "all arrive after 11:30" and $B$ be the event "all arrive before noon".

(1) asks for $P(\neg A\mid B)$, which is given by
$$1-\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$$
and this evaluates to
$$1-\frac{0.4773^{30}}{0.5^{30}}=0.7527$$
(2) asks for $P(B\mid\neg A)$. This can now be done with Bayes's theorem:
$$P(B\mid\neg A)=\frac{P(\neg A\mid B)P(B)}{P(\neg A)}=\frac{0.7527×0.5^{30}}{1-0.9773^{30}}=1.406×10^{-9}$$

Comment: I don't see where you get 0.4473. Isn't 11:30 _two_ standard deviations before noon?

Comment: @awkward And so it is - $0.9545/2=0.4773$. $0.9545$ is from the 68-95-99.7 rule.

Comment: Oops, you are so right!  Evidently I can't subtract today.